# Catch first submit

Tags: orbeon

I want to catch the first time the form "submit" button is pressed with a successful outcome and then set a value in a hidden field. Then I can set the form to read-only (with a button to reverse the read-only setting).

What's the best way of doing this via an action?

First attempt: https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/f4c3b0324026dd48dd7a219c3369ac921e29e12d

PeteA

Comment: From the orbeon tag: Use this tag for technical questions such as scripting issues, form behavior, etc. Non-technical questions should be directed to the Orbeon community at the official site.

Answer (score 0):

This is really something that you will want to do in the process that runs when users submit the form. Currently, this means that you will need access to the `properties-local.xml` (or whichever file is used to store the process) on the server.

In the `properties-local.xml`, in your submit process, use the `xf:setvalue` action ([doc](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-xforms#xf-setvalue)) to set the value of a field as needed, as in:

```
xf:setvalue(ref = "//submit-date", value = "current-date()")
```

Comment: The issue we have is that anyone who has the correct permission can re-enter a form and change data (whether intentionally or accidentally). 
So we would like to make the form "read-only" after the first successful submit. 
Then we could make a button visible which would then make the form changeable again (i.e. a positive action by the user).
We are open to any ideas/suggestions on how this could be done..

Comment: @PeteAtkin What you are describing looks like a special case of the situation described in this [blog post about workflows](https://blog.orbeon.com/2021/01/new-workflow-capabilities-in-orbeon.html). I might have pointed you to that post before, because it seems to me like a combination of actions you run when buttons are pressed (and yes, this requires you to edit the `properties-local.xml`), and form-level formulas ([doc](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/form-settings#formulas)) to make the whole form read-only upon some condition, is the way to go. Sounds like a plan?

Comment: We have spoken about this before, but we cannot access the properties-local.xml nor change the workflow state values.
So we're stuck with doing something within each form directly, hence this attempt here:
 https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/f4c3b0324026dd48dd7a219c3369ac921e29e12d

Comment: @PeteAtkin In your environment, is changing the `properties-local.xml` just "difficult", in the sense that you would need to ask someone else to do it, or is it completely impossible? I am asking because the right way to do this is really to update the process that runs when the user submits the form.

Comment: @PeteAtkin If the `properties-local.xml` can't be changed, by anyone, we would still need to know what the submit process does in your `properties-local.xml` to know what XForms we could add to the form to set a value upon submission. Are you able to ask someone for the code of that process, even if you are not allowed to modify it?

Comment: Hi Alex
Unfortunately we cannot even access the properties-local.xml file as its protected due to the nature of the Orbeon integration.
So we are stuck with 3 states: Initial, Updated and Completed(submitted)
I'll continue to find a solution within each form.

Comment: Hi @PeteAtkin, if you have this `completed` state, then you should be all set: you can just make the whole form readonly when the state is `completed`, this in the Form Settings, in the Formulas tab. Does it sound like this could work for you?

Comment: We've done this simple solution already Alex.
But we wanted a positive action by the user to re-open the form, so the thinking was:
1. On the 1st successful submit we make the form read-only, and also disable the SAVE button
2. An UNLOCK button is then visible and active for the user to press
3. On pressing the UNLOCK button the form fields and SAVE button are active gain

Comment: Hi @PeteAtkin, (a) You won't be able to disable the Save button if you can't change the `properties-local.xml`. (b) You could implement an Unlock button inside the form that changes the workflow stage. To do this you would need to add some XForms to the source of the form that listens on the button being pressed, and runs a `<xf:action type="xpath">fr:run-process('oxf.fr.detail.process', 'set-workflow-stage(name = "unlocked")')</xf:action>`, here changing the workflow stage to ` unlocked`. Would this help?

Comment: Thanks one again Alex
I will look at this one a little later as its dropped in priority...

Comment: Got it @PeteAtkin, and of course there is no rush on our side ;). As you are unable to modify the `properties-local.xml`, I think this capability of running any sequence of actions that you could have in a process from your own form, through the function `fr:run-process()`, can be quite powerful for you.

Comment: Many thanks Alex..
I'll have a look at fr:run-process() as you suggest..
PeteA